# What does the code "int nums[5]" do?

Tags: c++

What does `int nums[5];` do?  When I pass `nums` to `std::cout`, it prints a memory address I think, but I don't understand what the code itself is actually doing when it runs.

Comment: You'll want to learn what an *array* is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is array decaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: @NickyC: While that answer addresses the question of why `cout` prints a memory address for an array, it does not address the question actually asked here, so I do not think it is a duplicate, just additional useful info.

Answer (score 3):

`int nums[5];` allocates memory for a static array of 5 `int` values.

When you then do `std::cout << nums;`, it is actually calling `std::cout.operator<<(nums);`  While `std::cout` has many `<<` operators defined for many different type types, it does not have an `<<` operator that accepts an `int[]` array as input.  What it does have is an `<<` operator that accepts a `const void*` memory pointer as input.  It prints the value of the memory address that the pointer is pointing at.

A static array can "decay" into a pointer, in this case to an `int*`.

[What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/)

Any type of pointer can be assigned to a `void*`.  And any non-`const` variable can be assigned to a `const` variable of compatible type.  That is why the compiler does not complain when you call `std::cout << nums;`.  It is essentially acting similar to `std::cout.operator<<((void*)(int*)nums);` behind the scenes.

Answer (score -2):

'nums' is an array that holds 5 int type datas.For Example:
int nums[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

if you want to cout nums,you should write your code like this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < 5; index ++){
    std::cout<<nums[index]<<std::endl;
}
```

but ,if you want cout it's memory address,you should write your code like this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < 5; index ++){
    std::cout<<nums<<std::endl;
    nums ++;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.